Is it normal to get garbage output through UART when resetting the microcontroller?
I have written functioning code for Serial Communication through UART, and when stepping through the code it transmits characters just fine. I have done this using microlib, so I can use printf (I have implemented fputc() myself to achieve this.
I implemented this code as a learning effort, and now I am trying to use it to send errors just before the chip resets. To test this I have implemented an assert somewhere that always fails, which triggers the following code:
__attribute__((noreturn)) void J_on_assert_failed (char const *file, int line) {


    SM_PRINTF("[ASSERTION FAILED] File on line 36\n");
    SM_transmit_buffer();
    NVIC_SystemReset();

}
SM_PRINTF is simply a macro that does nothing if the serial monitor is disabled.
SM_transmit_buffer(); sends all characters in the buffer.
It is implemented this way, so I can use the idle thread to send the buffer (or earlier if the buffer is at capacity).
I am fairly certain that everything is going well until NVIC_SystemReset(); Then I suddenly get garbage:

21:34:12.167: JSM Logging enabled
Blinky blue thread started!
[ASSERTION FAILED] File on line 36½¥¹•¹…‰±•‘Š+Ëk+‰±Õ•Ñ¡É•…‘ÍÑ…ÉÑ•‘m[05]MM[15]IQ%=9[19][05]%1[15][11]u[19]¥±•½¹±¥¹•‰ê+ËË‹K+Ëk+‰±Õ(truncated here for clarity)

I have verified this by stepping through the code, and watching the received characters in a terminal. The buffer is also functioning as intended.
I have a suspcicion that I am simply seeing some artefacts from resetting the chip, and that the garbage is simply some eletrical effect being interpreted as data, however I am not sure.
Is this something I should fix, or is this normal? Should I simply disable the relevant UART before system reset?
Edit 1:
I have tried two new things (I lack an oscilloscope for tests), which are summarized in this snippet of code:
SM_PRINTF("[ASSERTION FAILED] File on line 36\n");
SM_transmit_buffer();
volatile int i = 1000;
while (i>0){
        i--;
}
//UART_disable(UART0);
NVIC_SystemReset();

I tried disabling the UART before the reset, which did nothing. I also implemented a delay long enough for the garbage characters to disappear. I suspect this means that the garbage is caused by not finishing the transmission before the chip resets.
So my next attempt will be to see if I can poll a register that waits for the transmission to complete, and only then to reset the chip.
I also saw some things about bootloaders potentially sending over UART, but I did not implement such a thing myself (I work from scratch), and I can only find in the datasheet that the ROM bootloader will be executed during reset.
I assume that the bootloader in my case is generated by my compiler and linker?
EDIT 2:
I have now fixed(?) it by waiting for the UART to complete sending the last character.
SM_PRINTF("[ASSERTION FAILED] File on line 36\n");
SM_transmit_buffer();
UART_delay_until_not_busy(UART0);
NVIC_SystemReset();

In my mind this works because I suspect I cut off the transmission whilst it is still sending bits, which confuses the hell out of the terminal running on my pc.
Based on the data-sheet, I also expect UART0 to be disabled during reset, and I don't think anything is send over it by a bootloader of some sorts (although I am not sure).
So, I suspect this is the solution, and that in my case it was not normal to see garbage during reset?
EDIT 3:
As per request, here is the code I use to transmit the characters:
void UART_write(UART0_Type* UARTn, uint8_t c){
    // Loop until the UART is no longer busy, then send another character.
    while(UARTn->FR & UARTFR_BUSY ){

    }
    UARTn->DR = c; // Put the character in the data register.

}

The chip I use is the Tiva TM4C123GH6PM on the EK-TM4C123GXL board from Texas Instruments.

To answer the question in the title: Yes, in my experience, this is common.  After a reset, one would typically flush the UART receive buffer before trusting its contents.

Agree with the above comment. Also one anecdotal possibility: when I reset my ESP32 I always get a bunch of garbage because the baud rate of the startup serial stuff is different than what my programs run. So its not garbage output but my COM port reads it as such, maybe a similar thing is what you're seeing.

So it will be correct to simply disable the UART before I reset, so I can avoid the garbage? I am only sending data from the microcontroller to my laptop in this case. I don't think the terminal I use on my laptop will be aware a reset has occurred and act accordingly.

You can try it, but I'm not sure that disabling the UART will carry over to the reset. One thing you could try is sending a codeword before and after a system reset that lets you know to avoid the garbage, but I'm not sure your application and what the problem with seeing this character dump is so tough to say.

I don't really have a "problem" with the character dump, as this is just an educational project for myself. I just took the character dump as a sign of me not understanding something and doing something wrong. Your solution of sending certain codewords is how people normally avoid this problem?

The problem does not go away if you disable the UART before reset - the reset disables the UART and the IO pin anyway until the firmware runs again and inits the IO pin and UART. You need to show the schematics. A simple fix might be a pull-up on MCU TXD to keep state stable during reset and PC RXD does not see garbage. As soon as you post hardware details between MCU and PC (and which MCU it is and does it jump to some bootloader first there can be a good answer.

To see what is actually "on the wire" you need an oscilloscope or logic analyzer. Record that last message and what happens afterwards. It might be some boot loader transmission with another baudrate. Mismatching baudrates commonly produce what we read as garbage.

Ah, sadly I don't have oscilloscope at the moment because I planned to occassionally borrow it from a friend, but I can share what MCU I use. It is the TM4C123GH6PM.
Meanwhile I also learned myself that indeed disabling the UART does not work. As an experiment I also put in a very dumb delay before the reset, and I found that making the delay long enough gets rid of more garbage the longer the delay is, until it disappears. I will update my question with what I exactly did.
Either way, this experiment makes me suspect that somehow the transmission has not properly finished before reset.

what is your implementation of fputc(), and what is the platform? do you simply write the character to the internal register and return? I suspect that if you wait until the character has finished sendind before returning (as an experiment) the issue might go away.

Ah, I just added this as my solution indeed. My implementation is that I wait for the the UART to be NOT busy, and then I place a character in the register. I will add the code to the question.

By the way, I found all the suggestions here very helpful, because it helps me to understand a lot more of what is going on in general, and I will no doubt use your suggestions if these problems pop up again. I hope I find a job soon again, too, so I can borrow an oscilloscope at work, or buy a cheap one myself.

on an esp32 move the uart to different pins.  the boot message will come out on the standard pins and be ignored.

My solution in the end was to implement a delay before the reset.
The code now delays until the UART has finished sending the last character, and only then the chip resets.
It is likely the garbage output was produced by resetting during transmission.
SM_PRINTF("[ASSERTION FAILED] File on line 36\n");
SM_transmit_buffer();
UART_delay_until_not_busy(UART0); // This is the solution.
NVIC_SystemReset();


I was wondering why you received the actual error message intact (but the final '\n'), but then I realized that the garbage could be your initial message(s) shifted by a number of bits. Serial communication is full of wonders, even after my 40+ years of its usage...

I don't know enough about the protocol yet, but you would expect that the software on the terminal side would figure out something is amiss with the start, stop and parity bits, too? Or perhaps I only saw characters that happened to produce valid data frames?

The latter is true, because serial communication is just a bit stream. If the receiving UART synchronizes on some random 0 as the start bit, and parity (if set) and stop bit(s) match, it will happily take the bits in between as data. However, this is only of academic value in your case. You need to know the exact parameters and for best results the actually sent data.

your call to SM_transmit_buffer();
returns as soon as the final '\n' is in the the transmitter shift register of the UART.
(it is not yet on the wire)
It is as this stage that the processor is reset by
NVIC_SystemReset(); and the baud rate is changed and boot messages are issued on the UART.
The easiest fix is probably to pad the message with a \xff after the '\n' unless there's a "fuse bit" you can set to alter the default baud rate of the UART to match your preferred rate.

I tried padding the message, but it did not work. As you can see in my edit above, implementing a delay did work, so I will see if I can delay a reset until the UART tells me the transmission is complete.
